# Etymology of "caber": why does it share conjugation with "saber"?

Tags: verbos, etimología

Can somebody tell me why "saber" and "caber" have identical conjugations (aside from the *c → qu* spelling change to maintain the hard *c* sound in "caber")?

There must be a historical etymological reason for this, but I can't see what it is, as the two words seem completely unrelated? Do we know what their latin root(s) is(are)?

---

**¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué los verbos "saber" y "caber" tienen la misma conjugación?**

No me sorprende que "saber" sea irregular, que es un verbo muy común, y en todo idioma los verbos más comunes suelen ser irregulares. Pero no veo por qué el verbo "caber" sigue su conjugación.

Tiene que haber alguna causa histórica y etimológica de eso. ¿Cuáles son las raíces latinas de estas palabras?

Comment: No es cierto que tengan exactamente la misma conjugación; se dice *Yo no quepo* pero jamás se dice *Yo no sepo* (lo correcto es *Yo no sé*).

Answer (score 3):

No soy un experto en lingüística pero creo recordar que hay muchas formas del latín que sufrieron modificaciones del castellano, entre ellas el cambio de "p" por "b", y de terminaciones como las que mencionas "-pere"->"-ber". De hecho en italiano, saber todavía se dice "sapere".

El origen de ambas palabras se resuelve con una consulta al [diccionario de la RAE](http://rae.es/rae.html):

> Saber: (Del lat. sapĕre).
>
> Caber: (Del lat. capĕre).

Las formas verbales son iguales, por lo que es normal que ambos tengan la misma conjugación (o casi) y mantengan la "p" en parte de las conjugaciones.

Answer (score 2):

Los verbos *saber* y *caber* provienen de los verbos latinos *capere* y *sapere* (ambos acentuados en la primera sílaba). La evolución fonética regular explica el cambio /p/ > /b/ entre vocales.

Otra evolución que se dio en algunas ramas del romance fue el desplazamiento de la acentuación de los infinitivos de este tipo, que pasó de la raíz a la desinencia (esto ocurrió en castellano y portugués pero no en francés e italiano, de ahí que digamos *vi**vir***, *vi**ver*** con acento en la última sílaba, pero ***vi***vre, ***vi***vere con acento en la primera). De no haber ocurrido esto los infinitivos serían **sáber*, **cáber*.

Por qué un verbo es irregular y otro no es una pregunta imposible de responder. *Caber* no es un verbo poco común y tal como se señala, los verbos muy usados, si son irregulares, tienden a continuar siéndolo, porque los hablantes los asimilan desde muy pequeños con todas sus formas anómalas. En este caso también puede haber sido muy importante la analogía. Las conjugaciones verbales irregulares se "ayudan" unas a otras cuando son compartidas por varios verbos, y en castellano tenemos *haber*, *saber* y *caber* siguiendo un modelo muy similar (en *habére* > *haber* había /b/ para empezar, que más tarde pasó a ser /v/, pero en castellano /v/ dio /b/  de nuevo de manera que para los fines prácticos dio lo mismo).

Más detalles en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-las-conjugaciones-con-cu-y-su-de-los-verbos-caber).

Answer (score -3):

Todo verbo en español se clasifica en una de tres familias, basado en como termina la forma del verbo en su forma infinitiva, -AR, -ER e -IR. Apartando los verbos irregulares (precisamente por su definición de irregular), los verbos en cada familia tienen conjugaciones  similares.

- Familia -AR: Amar, Alabar, Desarmar, etc.
- Familia -ER: Comer, Beber, Romper, etc.
- Familia -IR: Vivir, Escribir, Evadir

Comment: Precisamente el tema es que son irregulares...

Comment: Si de eso se tratara, la pregunta no hablaría de las conjugaciones (en su pregunta en inglés, habla de multiples conjugaciones, no solamente la de 1ra persona singular).

Comment: ¿Cómo se relaciona esta respuesta con la pregunta? No tiene sentido solo dar esta información completamente inútil que solo una persona que no sabe nada de español necesitaría y también escribir esa información en español.