# ¿Cuál es el origen de las conjugaciones con "cu-" y "su-" de los verbos "caber" y "saber"?

Tags: verbos, etimología, tiempos-verbales, historia

Partiendo de [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2960/12637), en la que se afirma que los verbos *saber* y *caber* tienen la misma conjugación porque vienen de verbos muy similares del latín que también se conjugaban igual, me dio por investigar y me encuentro con que las conjugaciones en latín (*[saber](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=sapio&Submit=Go&D1=9&H1=109)*, *[caber](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=capio&Submit=Go&D1=9&H1=109)*) carecían de los tiempos verbales comenzando con *cu-* o *su-* de estos verbos. Así, tenemos:

```
                    Sápere      Cápere       Actual
-------------------------------------------------------------
Perf. indicativo    sapuī       cēpī         supe, cupe
Plusc. indicativo   sapúeram    cḗperās      supiera, cupiera
Plusc. subjuntivo   sapuíssem   cēpíssem     supiese, cupiese
Futuro subjuntivo   sapúerō     cḗperō       supiere, cupiere
```

Como se puede ver, las conjugaciones no eran exactamente iguales, aunque sí muy parecidas. El caso es que ambos verbos evolucionaron de la misma forma, y han llegado hasta hoy con la misma conjugación, salvo casos particulares (*yo sé* en vez de *yo sepo*). En dicha evolución, hubo un momento en que las formas verbales pasaron de *sa-/ce-* a *su-/cu-*, y esa es mi pregunta: ¿cuándo ocurrió eso? ¿Por qué? ¿Tiene nombre este fenómeno? ¿Este fenómeno es único de estas formas o sucedió con otras palabras? Bueno, aparte de otros verbos con conjugaciones parecidas:

```
tenúeram -> tuviera
habúeram -> hubiera
```

Comment: Debo saber la razón sin investigarla pero la ignoro. Lo que sí puedo aportar de momentu es que antes de pasar a *-u-* en la raíz, primero hicieron escala, digamos, en *-o-*. Pero en general son verbos bastante irregulares en las lenguas neolatinas y de formas diferentes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En algún punto de la evolución del latín tardío, un grupo de verbos caracterizados por tener una raíz con un patrón fonético *C(C)-/a/-C* pasaron a formar perfectos en *-uī* por analogía con *habēre* (cuyo perfecto era *habuī*), entre ellos *sapēre* (luego confundido con *sapere*) y *capere*.

Luego la *u* del sufijo de perfecto hizo metátesis dando *au* en la raíz, que más tarde monoptongó en *o*.

Finalmente, un cambio posterior elevó la *o* a *u* en la raíz de todos estos verbos, por analogía con las formas de otros verbos similares que la habían elevado antes por influencia de una *i* en su conjugación (por ejemplo, *aduzir*).

- habēre: habuī → haubī → esp. ant. *ove* → esp. mod. *hube*
- sapere: sapuī → saupī → esp. ant. *sope* → esp. mod. *supe*
- capere: capuī → caupī → esp. ant. *cope* → esp. mod. *cupe*

(El diptongo *au* bloqueó la sonorización intervocálica de *p* en *b*, cosa que no ocurrió en portugués, donde el mismo principio dio lugar a los pretéritos modernos *houve*, *soube* y *coube*).

El pretérito de *tener* se formó aparentemente por analogía con *haber*, dado que los significados de ambos verbos eran muy similares y terminaban confundiéndose (fue *tove* primero y luego *tuve*). Muchos otros verbos se conjugaban de esta manera y fueron regularizados más tarde. Nuevamente la comparación con el portugués es útil para ver como estas cosas suelen ser contingentes: en castellano todavía decimos *anduve* mientras que el portugués tiene la forma regular *andou*, mientras que para nuestro *traje*, en portugués se tiene *trouxe* (que en castellano dio *truje*, forma todavía empleada en varios dialectos tanto europeos como americanos, antes de regularizarse por analogía).

**Fuente:** Paul M. Lloyd, *Del latín al español*, vol. 1, "Fonología y morfología históricas de la lengua española", versión española de Adelino Álvarez Rodríguez. Ed. Gredos, Madrid, 1993.

Comment: Nunca sabía que diptongos tal como _au_ bloquearon la sonorización de plosivos. De esto me voy a acordar. Seguro que hay muchos casos parecidos de los que ya no me voy a extrañar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ahí debió ser "Nunca supe". :) Revisando mi fuente, resulta que la [w] de *au* bloqueó la sonorización sólo de la /p/, no otras consonantes. Sucedió algo parecido con *capere* en *capio* > [kapjo] > [kajpo] > *quepo*.

Comment: ¡Gracias por ambas adiciones! ¿También explica por qué lo mismo no sucedió con _saber/sé_? ¿Sería que se ha apocopado por su frecuencia (_*sajpo_ > _*sεpo_ > _*sεp’_ > _se_) o algo así?

Comment: Según la misma fuente, es posible que haya habido una analogía con la forma correspondiente del verbo *haber* (*he*), que se había hecho monosilábica: *habeō* > [ajo] > [ej] > /e/. De *saber* habría derivado *_saio_ > [sej] > /se/. Es una conjetura pero parece que hay muchos casos de evolución analógica similar, donde un verbo "copia" a otro un patrón de conjugación.